# How is Spring IoC container able to create new Objects? Or does Spring IoC container work internally?

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

I googled a lot but didn't find/understand it how Spring IoC creates new objects.

I mean, normally we create it with the use of `new` keyword. Does IoC use `new` and is therefore able to create objects?

Answer (score 2):

Spring IoC container uses reflection internally to create instances and to do most of the stuff. And reflection API provides `newInstance()` methods to create objects.

Comment: Hi Juned...Thanks for the quick reply. Can you please elaborate what you have said above? Like an example will do for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes reflection is used to create instances by the spring IoC. 
Please check the descriptive answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43517470/9449599